# How to make textfield with pop out table view

Tags: swift

Hi I am looking to make a pop out table view similar to the one below and with selectable cells. Any help would be great thanks!
[Here is what I would like to style it after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJX1.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this is a great SO question because it's not a specific programming question... I would suggest getting the frame of the text field and then calculating an offset frame for a table and then add it to the view.

Comment: How? I feel like there's an easier way to doing it I'm just trying to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make use of UIPopoverPresentationController.

1. Make a tableviewController with the data you want to be able to select
2. Make a button that will send the action so you can present the popover
3. Do something with the item selected from the popover.

The second item above looks something like this (my own code example):

```
    @IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let controller = ShareVC()
      controller.socialPost = self.item
      controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
      // configure the Popover presentation controller
      let popController: UIPopoverPresentationController? = controller.popoverPresentationController
      popController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]
      popController?.delegate = self
      // in case we don't have a bar button as reference
      popController?.sourceView = sender
      popController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
      popController?.backgroundColor = .white

      self.parentViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { })
}
```

In my case the 'ShareVC" is a UITableViewController with item sharing options. Pretty similar to your screenshot as far as layout goes.

This will present that popover from the button that was tapped. Then again, you just need to handle the selection of the items from that ViewController.

Comment: This was very helpful except for some reason when I present the popController it doesn't anchor on my button. I have the sourcerect as sender.frame and sourceView = sender. Could this be something to do with constraints? or that I have the button on a scroll view? Also I would like to add to your answer that you need to import the UIPopoverPresentationDelegate.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting. If you are setting the source* items, I am not entirely sure why it wouldn't anchor properly. You may try playing with the permitted arrow directions, as if it were appearing somewhere that was compact on the screen, it can do some goofy stuff if the arrows can't layout properly.

Comment: I figured it out you have to have popController.sourceRect = sender.bound